# jqGrid using radio buttons for editable rows

Tags: jqgrid, radio-button

I'm currently using jqGrid and ASP.Net MVC. With my current project, my goal is to provide a grid of data to the end user, and they can then edit this. The data is machine-generated, and the users will be confirming if the machine is correct or not.

I think ideally for speed, I'd like to provide a row per item, with a radio button group as the editable. The users could then pick from the values 'Unknown', 'Correct', 'Incorrect'.

As there will be a lot of data, I'd also like to provide a control of some type that can set all rows in the grid to one of the available radio button choices, for the user experience.

Given that there seems to be no native support for this in jqGrid, I wanted to ask if anyone has had any experience writing something like this, and whether this is achievable and reliable, or whether I should stick with the drop-down editable approach that is native to jqGrid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To implement radio button as the editable instead of the standard drop-down editable approach you can use so named custom editing feature of jqGrid (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom). This allows you to create any custom control to edit the cell value. An example of the implementation you can find here: [Add multiple input elements in a custom edit type field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054811/add-multiple-input-elements-in-a-custom-edit-type-field/3055626#3055626).

To set all rows in the grid to one of the available radio button choices you can use either a control outside of jqGrid or add an additional custom button in the navigation bar (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons). If you search for `navButtonAdd` you will find a lot of examples how to implement this, for example, [Jqgrid: navigation based on the selected row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024075/jqgrid-navigation-based-on-the-selected-row/3024278#3024278). Because you use server based data, you can just call a method on the server to make the changes which you need and then call `trigger("reloadGrid")` to refresh jqGrid data.