# jqgrid - Set the custom_value of edittype: 'custom'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

The custom_value of place_id is set to whichever row I click first. Subsequent clicked rows will all use that same value, regardless of their actual value. Why?

**example:**

```
place_id foo_name bar_value
   10      blah       abc
   11      blah2      fgr
```

click the row with the place_id of 10 and click "edit" and the form that appears will have `10` for the place_id value. Make a change and save it then click the next row down. The form will still have the place_id of `10` though all other values will be correct.

**My code:**

The column place_id looks like this:

```
{name:'place_id', index:'place_id', editable: true, edittype:'custom',
 editoptions: { custom_element:myelem,custom_value:myval }}
```

The `myval` function is:

```
function myval(elem){
    return elem.val();
}
```

What I need is for the myval to be set to the correct place_id for the row being edited. I looked at the `elem` object in Firebug and I see that it always has the value of whichever row was first clicked but I don't understand why nor do I see where I can grab the correct value from. Any suggestions are appreciated (I tried asking on the jqgrid forums but nothing came of it so I'm turning to stackoverflow).

*Edit: If I use `edittype:'text'` rather than `edittype:'custom'` I get the correct values displayed and passed but then the column is editable and it should only be visible but not editable.

Full code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        url:'/foo/bar/results',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames:['Place ID', 'Site ID', 'Site Name', 'API ID', 'M Type'],
        colModel :[ 
            {name:'place_id', index:'place_id', key: true, sorttype:'integer',
             width:70, editable: true, edittype:'custom',
             editoptions: {custom_element:myelem,custom_value:myval }},
            {name:'site_id', index:'site_id', sorttype:'integer', width:70,
             editable: true, edittype: 'select', editrule: {required: true},
             editoptions:{value:getSites(), size:30}},
            {name:'site_name', index:'site_name', width:150, editable: false,
             editrule: {required: true}, editoptions: {size:30}},
            {name:'api_id', index:'api_id', sorttype:'integer', width:75,
             editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: {required: true},
             editoptions:{size:30}},
            {name:'m_type', index:'m_type', width:150, editable: true,
             edittype: 'select', editrules: {required: true},
             editoptions:{value:{'one':'one','two':'two','three':'three',
                                 'four':'four'},size:30}} 
        ],
        editurl:'/foo/bar/editinfo',    
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        pager: '#pager',
        viewrecords: true,
        loadonce: true,
        rowNum:20,
        rowList:[20,40,60,80,100],
        caption: 'Meter Listing'
    }); 

    // Edit functionality
    $("#editfields").click(function(){
        var gr = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
        if( gr != null ) { 
            jQuery('#list').setGridParam({datatype:'json'});
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('editGridRow',gr,
                           {editCaption: 'Edit Place Details',height:550,
                            closeAfterEdit:true,width:600,reloadAfterSubmit:true});
        } else {
            alert("Please select a row");
        }
    });
});

function myelem(value,options){
    return $('<input type="text" value="'+value+'" disabled="disabled"/>');
}

function myval(elem){
    return elem.val();
}
```

**edit2:**

getSites:

```
function getSites(){
    <?php
    $sites = "0:Select";
    foreach ($this->sites as $k => $v){
        $sites = $sites . ";" . $v['site_id'] . ":" . $v['site_name'];
    }
    ?>
    return "<?= $sites ?>";
}
```

Comment: Could you post also the code of `myelem` function?

Comment: added... though I don't really see where that `value` is coming from.... hmmm and `options` isn't even used.

Comment: Could you post code of `getSites` function?

Comment: I see where options is coming from now... the function uses call() to grab what it needs. Now, why is it grabbing the "wrong" thing?

Comment: I have added `getSites`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you try to include `key: true` in the definition of the `place_id` column. You can remove `id` from the data which you send from the server.

If it will not help, then you should post a full code example which reproduce your problem and I will try to find a workaround.

**UPDATED**: Sometime there are a simple solution for complex problems. One additional parameter of `editGridRow` function solve your problem:

```
recreateForm: true
```

Without using of the parameter the function `myelem` will be called **only one time at the first edit of the  selected row**. Then the form will be cached and **not recreated**. So you will be edit always the same row. After including of the parameter `recreateForm: true` the form will be created **every time**.

By the way I set some general settings which I use in all jqGrids per extending `jQuery.jgrid.defaults`, `jQuery.jgrid.edit`, `jQuery.jgrid.view`, `jQuery.jgrid.del` and `jQuery.jgrid.nav`. For example I use always

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {
    closeAfterAdd: true,
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    recreateForm: true,
   //...
});
```

Then I don't need set this parameters later. During writing of the answer [Add multiple input elements in a custom edit type field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054811/add-multiple-input-elements-in-a-custom-edit-type-field/3055626#3055626) about custom editing I has also the settings, so I didn't see any problems.

Comment: `key:true` did not help. I added a more complete code sample. Thanks for looking at this, Oleg.

Comment: If I refresh the page the place_id can be selected again and will be correct for that first selection. After that, though, the problem remains. Only reloading the page works.

Comment: That did it! Where did you find that parameter?! Did you already know about it or what? I looked over the wiki and simply never noticed that one. I was about to just force the page to reload with a brutish window.location.reload();

Comment: There are at least 3 places in wiki with the parameter. The main place in on http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing in the list of properties. Other place in the description of `dataInit`. About half of year I spend some days with some strange effect. I could fix the problem with the setting. After I reproduce your problem in debugger I could see that `myelem` will be called only one time. Then I remember about this parameter. At the end important, that the problem are solved. You can edit jqGrid Wiki yourself to recommend use `recreateForm: true` for custom editing.

Comment: Where do you stick the extended code? Like, would you create a file maybe named grid.extended.js, stick the code in there and then load that file along with the other jqgrid files?

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. I wrapped the extended object in a closure as well. Works perfectly! Thx!