# Custom dropdown formatter for jQuery jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, drop-down-menu, formatter

I am trying to format a cell on jqGrid so that when the user edits it they are presented with a custom implementation of a combobox (called activecombo) as the select html component is ugly.

I have read [this](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) and looked at the demos but they don't seem to do quite what I want. Here's what I have tried:

```
    var maritalStatusPickerFunction = function(cellvalue, options,
            rowObject) {
        var optionsArray = [ {
            "id" : 1,
            "status" : "Married"
        }, {
            "id" : 2,
            "status" : "Divorced"
        }, {
            "id" : 3,
            "status" : "Separated"
        }, {
            "id" : 4,
            "status" : "Widowed"
        }, {
            "id" : 5,
            "status" : "Unmarried"
        }

        ];
        var comboInput = $("<input type='text' value='" + cellvalue
                + "' />");
        comboInput.activecombo( {
            source : optionsArray
        });
        return comboInput;
    };

    $('#relationshipsGrid').jqGrid( {
        datatype : "local",
        colNames : [ 'Contact', 'Relationship' ],
        colModel : [ {
            name : 'contact',
            index : 'contact',
            width : 420
        }, {
            name : 'relationship',
            index : 'relationship',
            editable : true,
            formatter : maritalStatusPickerFunction,
            width : 120
        } ],
        width : 600,
        height : 100,
        cellEdit : true,
        editurl : "server.php"
    });
```

But that's obviously not what I am supposed to do as this just displays Object object in an input in a cell.

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Thanks,

Amy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need implement the custom implementation of a combobox during **editing** of the cell you should use the [custom editing control](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom) instead of the [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter).

Custom formatters are used to build HTML representation of the cell **as string**. Custom editing controls are used to create **custom DOM element** which will be placed inside the `<span>` element of the editing field. As an example see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054811/add-multiple-input-elements-in-a-custom-edit-type-field/3055626#3055626), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416572/jqgrid-set-the-custom-value-of-edittype-custom/3416853#3416853) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842262/jqgrid-implementing-of-custom-cell-integration-of-raty-plugin/4842450#4842450) old answers.

I don't know activecombo plugin, but it seems to me that you could don't write custom editing control. Instead of that you can try to define `dataInit` event handle inside of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions) like

```
editoptions: {
    dataInit : function (elem) { 
        $(elem).activecombo( {
            source : optionsArray
        }); 
    } 
}
```

or if ou will has any problem like

```
editoptions: {
    dataInit : function (elem) { 
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(elem).activecombo( {
                source : optionsArray
            }); 
        },100);
    } 
}
```

By the way you can do the same for the [searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config#colmodel_options). Then the user will have use the same advantages in the searching/filtering dialog.