# JQGrid Form editing button change text

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way to change the text display on the submit and cancel button in a JQGrid Form editing?

Comment: Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971453/how-to-add-different-texts-to-save-button-in-edit-and-add-forms-in-jqgrid/6971820#6971820) to exactly the same question. It is important to use `recreateForm: true` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing

You have the options bSubmit and bCancel which can be changed to the labels you need.

Comment: You are right, but it's important to use `recreateForm: true` option (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971453/how-to-add-different-texts-to-save-button-in-edit-and-add-forms-in-jqgrid/6971820#6971820)) additionally.