# jqGrid - hide column in form edit but visible in grid

Tags: jqgrid

I know jqGrid can hide the column in grid but visiable in edit form. Is there options for the other way around? In other words, does jqGrid have the option to hide the columns during form editing but visible in grid?

One useful scenario would be have a concatenated column composed of more than one columns, such as lastname + ' ' + firstname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at my previous answer [jqGrid: Disable form fields when editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405029/jqgrid-disable-form-fields-when-editing/3405961#3405961). It seems that is exactly what you need.

If you want to create some custom fields in the edit form which will look like not as  standard fields another answer could be also interesting [Add multiple input elements in a custom edit type field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054811/add-multiple-input-elements-in-a-custom-edit-type-field/3055626#3055626).

Comment: I have the same situation, except that I just want to viewrecords in modal not edit.  ie. View a hidden column but not show it in the grid.

Comment: @conqenator: I am not sure that I understand what you want, but you can make some changes in the column properties inside of `beforeInitData` handler (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484220/jqgrid-dynamic-form-change-label-in-formedit-add/4485643#4485643) as an example. Try to make the column visible (`hidden:false`) and change it back after closing the dialog. Use always `recreateForm:true` option. If you will have problems discribe the problem more exactly in the new question and post me the link to it.

Comment: @conqenator: I found your new question and wrote the answer here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645787/jqgrid-show-hidden-column-in-form-view/4651561#4651561