# jqgrid dynamic form change label in formedit/add

Tags: jqgrid

i have a form 
....

```
{
    width:450,height:350, //1
    beforeShowForm: function(formID) {     
        recreateForm: true,
        alert("Really?") ; 
        jQuery('#tr_b_date',  formID).show();
        jQuery('#tr_buchung', formID).show();  

        jQuery('#tr_b_menge_lsv',  formID).hide();
        jQuery('#tr_b_text_lsv',   formID).hide(); 
        jQuery('#tr_b_summe_lsv',  formID).hide(); 
        jQuery('#tr_b_menge_cvvp', formID).hide();
        jQuery('#tr_b_text_cvvp',  formID).hide(); 
        jQuery('#tr_b_summe_cvvp', formID).hide();  

        jQuery('#buchung', formID).change(function() { 

            var index = $(this)[0].selectedIndex;
            if (index == 1) {
                jQuery("#kundenbuchung").setColProp('LSV',
                                                    {formoptions:{label:'TEST1'}});
                jQuery("#kundenbuchung").setColProp('Count_L',
                                                    {formoptions:{label:'TEST2'}});
                jQuery('#tr_b_summe_lsv', formID).show();     
                jQuery('#tr_b_text_lsv',  formID).show(); 
                jQuery('#tr_b_menge_lsv',  formID).hide(); 
                jQuery('#tr_b_menge_cvvp', formID).hide(); 
                jQuery('#tr_b_text_cvvp',  formID).hide(); 
                jQuery('#tr_b_summe_cvvp', formID).hide();
            } 
            else if (index == 2) { .....`
```

I want to change the labels in the form dynamicly, but

```
jQuery("#kundenbuchung").setColProp('LSV',    {formoptions: { label: 'TEST1' }} );
jQuery("#kundenbuchung").setColProp('Count_L',{formoptions: { label: 'TEST2' }} );
```

doesn't work. Any Ideas?
Schalotte

Answer (score 2):

Inside of `beforeShowForm` the form is already created. You can tried to change `label` inside of `beforeInitData`.

Another way is to change

```
jQuery("#kundenbuchung").setColProp('LSV', {formoptions: {label:'TEST1'}})
```

to

```
jQuery('tr#tr_LSV > td.CaptionTD', formID[0]).html('TEST1')
```

or something about this. I recommend you to use [recreateForm:true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties) option to be sure that `beforeShowForm` will be called at every row editing.

Comment: Hello Oleg, thanks a lot: jQuery('tr#tr_LSV > td.CaptionTD', formID[0]).html('TEST1') works very well

Comment: @Oleg May you see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999261/change-label-text-add-form-in-jqgird   I am stuck