# To create label suffix like element suffix in formoptions in jqgrid editable options

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

How to apply * after form label from jqgrid through mvc3 model, like ex:-Username:*. I want label suffix like element suffix from form options. How can I create label suffix in form options

Comment: I am unclear what you are asking?  You want a suffex where? In the grid? In a column name? In the grid caption? What form are you speaking of?

Comment: Thanks Mark for response.
What I mean is I want the asterisk symbol after label(Name) but not before textbox as you shown. In above example you shown it disturbs the allignment of the controls also. Example- 
Name:*    TextboxControl
Date:*    TextboxControl
Ship Via: DropdownControl
The label names (Name,Date)are loaded dynamically.

Comment: My labels are dynamically loaded from database, not set using label attribute. So I want the form labels are suffixed with * which are different from column heades in jqgrid. Please find below code I am using to set column headers and formlabels dynamically. //This line updates the ColNames array through jqGrid. If done this way the edit form will also use those names. // This trick will not work if we have set the FormLabel property in the JqGridColumnEditable attr in the Entity Model. $(gridId).jqGrid("setLabel", fieldLablesData[i].ColumnName, fieldLablesData[i].CustomLabel);

Answer (score 2):

It's really difficult to understand what you exactly mean. If I understand you correctly you can use `label` property of [formoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#formoptions) to solve your problem. The value of `label` property could be any common HTML fragment. For example the setting below

```
formoptions: {
    elmprefix:"&nbsp;&nbsp;(<span class='mystar' style='color:red'>*</span>)&nbsp;",
    elmsuffix:"&nbsp;&nbsp;yyyy-mm-dd",
    label: "<span>Date<span><span style='float:right'>XXX</span>"
}
```

set two spans as the label of the form. As the result you can produce forms like below (see the field Date)

[image]

**UPDATED**: The usage of `formoptions.label` or `formoptions.elmprefix` are two way which you can use. If you want to set `formoptions.label` with any *dynamical* values you can do this with respect of `$(this).jqGrid("setColProp", "yourColumnName", {formoptions: {label: "any HTML or text string"}})`. If you would make the call inside of `beforeInitData` callback (like in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4485643/315935)) jqGrid will use new modified labels in the form. You should don't forget to use `recreateForm: true` option of the form editing (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6128195/315935) examples).

Comment: Thanks Oleg for your reply. What I mean is I want the asterisk symbol after label(Name) but not before textbox as you shown. In above example you shown it disturbs the allignment of the controls also. Example- UserName:* TextboxControl

Comment: @user1997213: I suggested you to use **`label`** property (see "XXX" part in the form). It allows you to place **any information** on the place of label. You can use multiple `<span>`, `<div>` and so on. Using CSS you can do what you want. Additionally I shown that one can use `elmprefix` to place any information *before* controls. If you would use `elmprefix` with some spaces (`&nbsp;`) for all other fields then you will have the same results like placing `*` at the end of `label`. So I tried to show you *multiple* ways to solve your problem.

Comment: My labels are dynamically loaded from database, not set using label attribute. So I want the form labels are suffixed with * which are different from column heades in jqgrid. Please find below code I am using to set column headers and formlabels dynamically.
//This line updates the ColNames array through jqGrid. If done this way the edit form will also use those names.
// This trick will not work if we have set the FormLabel property in the JqGridColumnEditable attr in the Entity Model.

$(gridId).jqGrid("setLabel", fieldLablesData[i].ColumnName, fieldLablesData[i].CustomLabel);

Comment: @user1997213: Look at the "**UPDATED**" part of my answer.

Comment: Ok Great. But how to identify the required field of all properties(to give columnname as tr_columnname) on form load.I am unable to identify what are the fields marked with [Required] attribute in Model on form load.

Comment: @user1997213: I'm not sure that I understand you correctly. If you have information which you need on the server side you can send in as the part of JSON response from the server. Inside of `beforeProcessing` or `loadCompleted` callbacks you will have full access to all information from the server response. So you can either change `formoptions.label`, `editrules.required` or any other column settings directly inside of the callbacks or you can save required information in a variable and use it whenever it will be needed.

Comment: Thank You Oleg for your responses. The below code did trick for me.
     function markRequiredFields(gridName)
        {
        var colmodel=$(gridName).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'),i=0,l=colmodel.length;
          for (i=0; i < l; i += 1) {
                    if(colmodel[i].hasOwnProperty("editrules") && colmodel[i].editrules.hasOwnProperty("required") && colmodel[i].editrules.required ===true ){
                        $('#tr_'+colmodel[i].name+ ' td.CaptionTD').append('<span style='+'color:Red'+'>*</span>');
                    }
                }
        }