# hide label in jqgrid Add form

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way to completely hide the label of a text field inside Add form?
I guess it should be inside **beforeInitData** event.
I want only the text box visible in my form. How to achieve this.
any idea??
Many thanks.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Solved! for solution visit this   
[url][1]          
 Many thanks oleg.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484220/jqgrid-dynamic-form-change-label-in-formedit-add