# change label text Add Form in jqgird

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to change the label text of `StudentOrEmployeeId`   which is currently 'Name'. My change event is working but unable to change the name.May I am missing something

```
colNames: ['IssueType', 'Issued To','Name']
  { name: 'IssueType', index: 'IssueType', align: 'center', editable: true, edittype:  'select',
        editoptions: 
         {
          value: "0:Student;1:Teacher",
          dataEvents: [{
          type: 'change',
          fn: function (e) {
           if ($('#IssueType option:selected').val() == 0)                        
           {                           
          jQuery('tr#StudentOrEmployeeId > td.CaptionTD').html('Student Id')
            }
            else
           {                                       
           jQuery('tr#StudentOrEmployeeId > td.CaptionTD').html('Employee');
                              }
                              }
                            }], }
                      },
           { name: 'StudentOrEmployeeId', 'index': 'StudentOrEmployeeId', editable: true, },
```

Answer (score 0):

`label` property of [formoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#formoptions) of `colModel` can be used to specify the label of Add/Edit form.

Comment: sorry, On the change event of one column dropdown value, I need to change the label of another column label, not column header text