# jqgrid radio button

Tags: radio-button, jqgrid

I was trying to define a jqgrid column as a radio button group, but I could not.
Anybody knows what I have to do? Please give me an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if you define [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#custom_formatter) and [custom unformatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting). If you will need to edit the cells/rows with radio buttons you will have to implement also [custom editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054811/add-multiple-input-elements-in-a-custom-edit-type-field/3055626#3055626). You can do implemant all this, but I would **not recommend** to do this. I recommend you to conside to use select formatter instead and use it together with [stype:'select'](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config#colmodel_options). Radio button group shows mostly the same information, but in more compact form. If you do need to use radio button then I would you recommend you to use there only during cell/row editing.