# Jqgrid edit field into multiple inputs

Tags: php, jqgrid

in jqgrid am showing person name as "Firstname + Lastname" in a single column. but when i click on edit it will become one input field but i want it to be two inputs field one for firstname and other one for lastname.

for example:
take any jqgrid table and assume there is one more column "name" having values like "Rahul garg", "Jack oberoi", "Gordon Linoff"..   when i edit it it will be like

`<input  type="text"  class="formelement" name="name" value="Rahul garg">`

but i wanted it to be like

`<input  type="text"  class="formelement" name="first_name" value="Rahul">
<input  type="text"  class="formelement" name="last_name" value="garg">`

Comment: Please be more specific and clear what you want to be done. And also let us know what have you done yet

Comment: for example take any jqgrid table and assume there is one more column "name" having values like "Rahul garg", "Jack oberoi", "Gordon Linoff"..   when i edit it it will be like 

<pre><input  type="text"  class="formelement" name="name" value="Rahul garg"></pre>

but i wanted it to be like 
<pre>
<input  type="text"  class="formelement" name="first_name" value="Rahul">
<input  type="text"  class="formelement" name="last_name" value="garg"> </pre>

Comment: @PritamJinal: Look at [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3055626/315935), which seems to me the exact answer on your question. It you would still have some questions opened I could try to help you. It could be important how you hold the data for `last_name` and `first_name`. You can hold both fields separately and just *display* composite (virtual) full name based on `last_name` and `first_name`. During editing you modify the first and the last name and the column formatter will just display new  composite full name fter finishing of editing.

Comment: yes thats solves my problem...  am holding both fields as hidden and showing composite full name...   thanks..